# How to pass dynamic values to CXF OutInterceptor?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, cxf

I have a webservice client using `CXF` and `Spring`.

The client proxy is created as spring managed `@Bean`, and registered to the `SpringBus`.

The soap webservice requires a HTTP header named "Auth=[pass]", whereas pass must be a dynamic value, unique for each user that uses the client.

Here is the problem: I created an `AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor` that puts the HTTP header before sending the XML to the webservice.

Which works fine for hardcoded pass. But I need to obtain the pass inside the interceptor dynamically. Therefore, I would somehow have to pass the currently logged in user INTO the interceptor itself. So that the interceptor then could fetch the proper authorization pass.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Autowired
    SpringBus bus;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        bus.getOutInterceptors().add(new AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor(Phase.MARSHAL) {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
               Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>) message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);
               headers.put("Auth", Arrays.asList("dynamic pass per user"); //TODO how to get the current user dynamically?
            }
        });
    }   

    @Bean
    public WebservicePort getPort() {
        WebservicePort port = new Webservice(bus);
        return port;
    }
}



@Service
public class WebserviceClient {
    @Autowired
    private WebservicePort port;

    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;

    public void run() {
        //construct the xmlRequest

        User user = authService.getCurrentUser();  
        port.send(xmlRequest); //invoke the auto-generated webservice stub
    }
}
```

Of course I cannot change the auto generated method signature `send(xml)`.
How can I get the current user into the `OutInterceptor` at time of sending dynamically, and just for this send request?

It must be threadsafe regarding the cxf client proxy, as multiple user might send a request simultaneously.

Comment: From where you are getting username and password? for UI or from DB?

Comment: @KarthikPrasad does it matter? Important is here that user+pass are dynamic values that are to be injected just before sending the xml request, but without interfering with simultaneous requests. To answer your question: in my application I get the username from UI, and based on this pick user+pass credentials from DB for the webservice req. The username serves as some kind of `@Id` here.

Comment: Need to do the same thing. Did you find a solution?